# Dynamically parsing row cells of excel file in VB using Microsoft.Office.Interops.Excel COM

Tags: vb.net, excel, parsing, com

I've been attempting to feed a variable to a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet.Cells` call, but its proving to be very finicky.

I do this in a loop, and I'd like to incorporate the rowcount in the cell to parse like so:

#### Have this:

```
Dim rng As Excel.Range = CType(worksheet.Cells(1, 1), Excel.Range)
```

#### Want This:

```
Dim rowCount As Integer = 1
Dim rng As Excel.Range = CType(worksheet.Cells(i, 1), Excel.Range)
                                              ^^
```

#### But I'm getting this exception:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

and stepping through my local variables in the debugger, I get this sad message for `rng.Value`:

```
In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user.
```

I'm interpreting that to mean that cell range index needs to be set explicitly (like actually putting in `....Cells(1,1) )`.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? If not, how can I parse this cell dynamically as I loop through the rows of my excel application?

#### Full Code:

```
 Dim app As New Excel.Application
            Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
            Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim rowCount As Integer = 0
            Dim range As Excel.Range

            workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(specsheetName, [ReadOnly]:=False)
            worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            range = worksheet.UsedRange

            updateStatusLabel.Text = range.Rows.Count.ToString() & ", " & range.Columns.Count.ToString()
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 1 To range.Rows.Count
                Dim msg As String
                Dim Obj As Excel.Range = CType(worksheet.Cells(i, 1), Excel.Range) '<--BREAKS HERE!

                If Obj.Value.ToString.Contains("Device Prefix") Then
                    msg = worksheet.Range("B1").Value().ToString()
                    updateStatusLabel.Text = msg
                    Return '***** adding this is what did it.
                Else
                    updateStatusLabel.Text = "not found"
                End If

                rowCount = rowCount + 1
            Next
            app.Workbooks.Close()
```

#### Again, the code runs for assignment `.Cells(1,1)` but not for `.Cells(i,1)` (subtle difference)

Thanks in advance!

### UPDATE: SOLUTION FOUND

*I was able to add a `Return` after "updateStatusLabel.Text = msg` (ie after the cell I'm looking to parse is found, and everything worked great. I guess I'm just not used to the VB looping system. I don't understand why that worked. See above code for change.

Comment: if you are doing it in a loop, when you get the NRE, rowcount  might be an illegal value resulting in a null Range

Comment: Please post your full code

Answer (score 0):

The Exception that you get let me think your excel workbook isn't correctly loaded.

please try this :

```
        Dim excelApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
        excelApp.Visible = False
        Dim excelWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\MyPath.xls")
        Dim worksheet As Worksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim rowCount As Integer = 10
        For i = 1 To rowCount Step 1
            'Get the Excel cells
            Dim rng As Excel.Range = worksheet.Cells(i, 1)
        Next
```

Comment: Did you test this? wouldn't a cell value of (0,1) be out of range (because there is no "0" row)?

Comment: The question I have is not an issue of being out of range, however, it is specifically *whether it is possible to use a Integer type variable assignment to the Cell(row, column) indices. See above for my snippet that works, compared to what does not work.